# Charges in different mediums

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

Generally we read or solve problems about charges in the same medium.

I wonder what would happen if the two charges were placed in different mediums. eg.) One is placed in vaccum and other is placed in a dielectric.

The concept would be that dielectric would get polarised  due to the charges and net force of attraction or repulsion between the charges would decrease.

But I cannot understand this from a mathematical point of view like will the permittivity of the mediums add or what?
Please help me to understand this mathematically.

Note: This is not a homework question. 
Also there seems a similar question on Stackexchange but the answer to it seemed unsatisfactory to me because the answer used a special case to explain the case and not a general one. Also there were a lot of comments questioning the answer. That's why decide to ask a new question.